# Apply prometheus metric for specific deployment

Tags: prometheus, grafana, dashboard, metrics, monitor

This metrics return the runnig time of specific pod

```
sum by(namespace, pod) (

   (last_over_time(kube_pod_completion_time[1d]) 
   - last_over_time(kube_pod_created{pod="consumer-deployment-697bcc9d8-sl9lj"}[1d])) 

  or 

    (time() - kube_pod_created{pod="consumer-deployment-697bcc9d8-sl9lj"})

)
```

and this

```
kube_pod_created{})
```

return all pods how can I make it retrun only result from specific deployment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v found a solution that worked for me I'v added

```
pod=~"consumer-deployment.*"
```

so it list only pods start with that prefix

final query is

```
kube_pod_created{pod=~"consumer-deployment.*"}
```